# Binary event protocol

Tags: java

I have developed an application that usually runs headless as a server module.

However the tool would benefit greatly from two things:

- pluggable viewers that see what is going on (easy enough)
- pluggable modules by which I mean the tool can generate events and you should be able (from a client tool) to connect to the server tool and temporarily register an event subscriber which can manipulate the server behavior based on the events (in realtime, so the events are **not** async)

The first can easily be achieved with a http server or the likes but the modules require a persistent connection. My language of choice is java but I'd rather not go for RMI but instead opt for a language-agnostic protocol. Any ideas which protocol would be uniquely suited for this situation and which might already have an implementation in java?

Comment: Why not just use a simple Socket and send binary messages? Easy to implement, low overhead.

Comment: Even then one needs a minimal protocol and sure I can roll my own but I was wondering whether one already existed. Existing solutions would bring experience and working code to the table.

Comment: Have you checked out the Atmosphere framework? Look at the wasync client too.

Comment: Have done this a lot - server apps that need minimal instructions and info sharing capabilities. Two of the quick and work okay techniques is :

1. if a lot of params need to be  passed use a http POST, this way we can take all the benefits of a well documented protocol. Easy to find code

2. use simple text commands with a simple separator like two \n\n http://quickserver.org/ has some samples

Comment: see http://quickserver.org/docs/2.0.0/org/quickserver/net/qsadmin/QSAdminAPI.html

Answer (score 1):

Another couple of options might be Akka (www.akka.io) actors in Java and/or Camel as event distribution mechanisms.   I'm an Akka guy myself.

To me, you'd write your Akka event handlers in Java and those would be your modules.

Comment: Akka looks interesting, I'll look into it.